# C# splitting string into comboboxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm making a decimal to HEX converter. The decimal number is typed into a textbox by the user and there are 8 comboboxes, one for each possible digit.
The method i have written takes the input string from the textbox and converts the decimal number to hexadecimal and returns it as a string.

How can I put the returned string (hex number) into the correct comboboxes from "cboHex0" to "cboHex7", going from least significant bit to MSB.

Tried this but it does not work.
Appreciate all help as I am new to stackoverflow and C#.

```
void decimalToHex(long dec)
        {
            if ((dec < 1) || (dec > 4294967295))
            //if ((dec < 1) || (dec > 4294967295))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR\r\n" +
                    "Decimal number is not within the range for conversion");
                return "0";
            }



            long hex = dec;
            string hexStr = string.Empty;

            while (dec > 0)
            {
                hex = dec % 16;

                if (hex < 10)
                    hexStr = hexStr.Insert(0, Convert.ToChar(hex + 48).ToString());
                else
                    hexStr = hexStr.Insert(0, Convert.ToChar(hex + 55).ToString());

                dec /= 16;
            }

            //return hexStr;

            //splitte streng til array.
            string[] stringElements = hexStr.Split('');
            stringElements.Reverse();

            if (stringElements.Length > 0)
            {
                cboHex0.Text = stringElements[0];
            }

            if (stringElements.Length > 1)
            {
                cboHex1.Text = stringElements[1];
            }

            if (stringElements.Length > 2)
            {
                cboHex2.Text = stringElements[2];
            }

            if (stringElements.Length > 3)
            {
                cboHex3.Text = stringElements[3];
            }

            if (stringElements.Length > 4)
            {
                cboHex4.Text = stringElements[4];
            }

            if (stringElements.Length > 5)
            {
                cboHex5.Text = stringElements[5];
            }

            if (stringElements.Length > 6)
            {
                cboHex6.Text = stringElements[6];
            }

            if (stringElements.Length > 7)
            {
                cboHex7.Text = stringElements[7];
            }

        }
```

Edit:
Okay so seems that I can *target* a character from a string by stringName[index].

So if the returned string is "1AF", how can I code so that the 8 comboboxes will show 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , A , F ?

Comment: Can you explain `does not work`?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to split the string so that each symbol in the string is its own element in an array. (NOt sure if this is the best approach.) And then putting them into their respective comboboxes.
But i cant figure out how to put symbols into their comboboxes. Also the split seems it cannot split without delemiter. I want to split between each character.

Comment: FYI you can just do `var hexStr = dec.ToString("x");` to get the hexadecimal string representation

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: Split only splits at a delimiter. If you want each character at a specific position, use an index on the string. e.g. hexStr[0] will retrieve the hex character at the 0 position.

Comment: Do you mean you want each character?  If so you can just do `hexStr[n].ToString()` to get the character at position n in a string.

Comment: You don't need `stringElements`. You can do `hexStr[0]`

Comment: @juharr wow thanks! For the trick.

Comment: Updated the post with new information

Comment: Second edit answer `PadLeft("0")`

Comment: @Charlieface I don't understand. How should I implement this in the code?

Comment: If you do `dec.ToString("x8")` then you'll get leading zeros up to 8 digits.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up using this `var hexStr = (dec.ToString("x8")).ToUpper();`

Comment: @VaBraAnton If you want upper case just do `dec.ToString("X8")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to make the work easier, make your result a consistent length:

```
hexStr = hexStr.PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Then, you can simply assign the boxes as follows:

```
cboHex0.Text = hexStr.Substring(0,1);
cboHex1.Text = hexStr.Substring(1,1)
cboHex2.Text = hexStr.Substring(2,1);
```

etc.

Comment: `PadLeft(8, '0')`?

Comment: I believe the OP wants to put one hex digit in each text box, not pairs of digits.

Comment: @juharr, correct. Didn't use .substring, instead used:
`cboHex0.Text = hexStr[7].ToString();
            cboHex1.Text = hexStr[6].ToString();
            cboHex2.Text = hexStr[5].ToString();` and so on